# Question related to optics

Tags: optics, visible-light

My teacher asked me a question, the question is this "Sunlight enters into a room thorugh a triangular aperture, when i place a screen nearer to the aperture it casts a triangular image, but when the screen is far away from the circular aperture, it casts circular image. Why?  My answer is due to the diffraction of light, but my teacher asked me to think about it again and wants us to answer the question within a week. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Your teacher is right, it's not due to diffraction.

Comment: hint: As your screen is getting away from the aperture, the shadow is losing the sharp characteristic nature of the edges and hence it is hard to distinguish between a polygon of finite number of sides (a triangle in your case) and a circle (which can be thought of as a polygon of infinite number of sides.)

Comment: @Benjamin Do you mean, the sunlight is not coherent source,  so it diverges more with increasing distance?

Comment: Sun is not a coherent source. In fact you don't have much coherent sources in Nature. But this has nothing to do with the logic. So, think of all other optical phenomena.

Comment: Hint: think about a [pinhole camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinhole_camera)

Comment: Veritasium has a nice video about this, you should check it out.